# How to add the word "by" before an author?

Tags: formatting, author

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \title{%    
            {\textbf{Story Name}}\\
            {\large a Textual Analysis}\\}
    \author{Author}
    \date{}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

So say I have what is written above, what is the best way to add "by author" instead of just having the authors name listed underneath of the title? I want "by" to be centered, and above the name of the author.

Comment: Hi, Kalcifer! What about `\author{\small BY\\Author}` ?

Comment: @Jinwen That seems to do the trick more or less! I ended up modifying it a bit and added a second \\ after "by" for a total of \\\\ to get some extra whitespace.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments